# Use Reflection to call Cast fails with Parameter count mismatch exception

Tags: c#, linq, generics, reflection, radgridview

I have collection of type Foo.
It is bind to a RadGridView's ItemsSource.
I want to get all current items from RadGridView using below code -

```
var current_collection = gv.Items.Cast<Foo>().ToArray();
```

I want to do the above dynamically using reflection, but having trouble making it run, below is my code so far -

```
var t = gv.ItemsSource.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Single();
```

Here t is Foo type.

```
var x = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast").MakeGenericMethod(t).Invoke(gv.Items, null);

var y = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToArray").MakeGenericMethod(t).Invoke(x, null);
```

Parameter count mismatch exception on above code.

Comment: But when you call `Invoke` it will return an `object` which isn't going to be a lot of help as you'll have an `IEnumerable<>` in it. How will you enumerate over it?

Comment: Again using reflection to call ToArray() on it.

Comment: but if you use reflection again you'll just end up with another object. If your code never mentions a concreate type then you mist as well just work with a sequence of `object`. Perhaps add an example of how you intend to use the data after you've run the reflected methods.

Comment: I intend to do processing on y, like convert to csv or html.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question, but after you've called `ToArray` what will you do the result? You seem to be doing a lot of work to end up with an object (which is the type of `y`) rather than just saying `gv.Cast<object>().ToArray()` for example.

Comment: If you're looking to do something like CSV or HTML conversions then you'll need to do reflection on the objects in the collection rather than the collection itself.

Comment: I want a generic implementation, so I can avoid this var current_collection = gv.Items.Cast<Foo>().ToArray();

Comment: You don't need that!!! If you change your question to state what you're actually trying to do, which is to generically process a sequence of objects where the type is determined at runtime, you'll get a more useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods that you are trying to call are **static**, so when using [`Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx), you should pass `null` to `object obj` argument and pass the required arguments via `object[] parameters` argument:

```
var x = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast").MakeGenericMethod(t)
    .Invoke(null, new object [] { gv.Items });

var y = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToArray").MakeGenericMethod(t)
    .Invoke(null, new object[] { x });
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that they are static, works perfectly.

Comment: Care to explain why, since they are extension methods and are used as instance method invoked on objects.

Comment: Extension methods are plain static methods with compiler sugar support to be used in normal code **like** instance methods. However, the reflection has nothing in common with the compilers and compiler sugars, so the methods has to be called exactly the way they are actually (`instance` or `static`).

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it to invoke those methods

```
        var x = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast").MakeGenericMethod(t).Invoke(null, new object[] { gv.Items });
        var y = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToArray").MakeGenericMethod(t).Invoke(null, new object[] {x });
```

Comment: You were also right but you didn't mention that they were static.